# Cannot get cmd command result from C# code

Tags: c#, shell, cmd, plink

I am using a switch and I want to connect it via ssh or telnet and send commands to specific ports. I succeeded connecting to the switch but I am not able to execute commands after login.

```
string command = "reboot";
using (Process process = new Process())
{
     process.StartInfo.FileName = "plink.exe";
     process.StartInfo.Arguments = "admin@192.168.42.7 -pw admin " + command;
     process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
     process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
     process.Start();
}
```

Code given above logins to the switch interface but not execute the command. 
It hangs with **switch#** text.

I tried a couple of things from cmd and I am able to get command on the screen after login but now I cannot get the same result when I write same text in C# code.

**plink.exe admin@192.168.42.7 -pw admin < D:\input.txt** --> this works when executed from cmd not in C#.

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
     process.StartInfo.FileName = "plink.exe";
     process.StartInfo.Arguments = "admin@192.168.42.7 -pw admin < D:\\input.txt";
     process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
     process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
     process.Start();
}
```

What could be the reason? Thanks

Comment: Are you missing a space after "-pw admin"?

Comment: No, I am sorry but I think this is not that easy. I am facing with that problem more than 1 day.

Comment: The code you have is passing the arguments as "admin@192.168.42.7 -pw adminreboot".  I don't think you want "adminreboot" all as one word do you?

Comment: I edited my question :)

Comment: It is the command processor that implements the `<` operator.  You must therefore start Cmd.exe instead.  Use its -c option to pass the command line.  Start with -k so you can see errors.

Comment: @snvngrc - Set the filename for process' StartInfo as `cmd`, and pass plink.exe in the Arguments. Check if that helps.

Comment: Do not drive an external console application for implement SSH. Use a native .NET class instead!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I tried SshClient already. But it also doesn't work.

Comment: So ask a question about `SshClient`, instead of hacking with an external application.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks for the answer but it didn't work.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl If SshClient didn't work already, why am I asking my question about it?

Comment: You can do much more with `SshClient` than with Plink. In other words, there's nothing you can do with Plink, that you cannot do with `SshClient`. Just because you didn't manage to make `SshClient` work, does not mean that it cannot work.

Comment: It seems like you can manage easily. Then why don't you help me instead of writing unnecessary comments?

Comment: I've linked a question with an answer to your question about plink. - If you want a help with `SshClient`, you have to ask a new question with a code that you have tried, and good description of problems that you face with it.